# How to use group theory to solve larrys square iphone app

Tags: group-theory, permutations, puzzle, rubiks-cube

There's a 2 d version of rubiks cube on apple app store. How can group theory give an algorithm to solve the iPhone app:larry's square.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is similar to a rotation puzzle game on old Nokia phones. Here's a discussion on Google groups which is pretty old.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.puzzles/wPoSeQv1xYY

Comment: +1 for the ref. It starts with 2x2 rotations, but moves on to 3x3